# Django range input instead of text

Tags: python, html, django

I am using django forms as you can see in the view.py file and the result is to have a text box.I can submit values numbers and then use this numbers to run script.py etc. I want to do the same with a range input instead of text so that every time the value on the slider change.

My views.py

```
def get_name(request):
form = NameForm()
if request.method == 'POST': 
    a = request.POST['your_name'] # do somethink with the value entered in the form
    print(a)
    a = int(a) 
    while a>0:
        print(a)
        a = a -1

return render(request, 'personal/code2.html', {'form': form})
```

My code2.html

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}
{% block content %}

<form action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form}}
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

And my forms.py

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
  your_name = forms.DurationField(label='% Brightness ')
```

Comment: Take a look at http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#a-slider

Comment: I've try to use it but i can't make it work. Could you help more?

Comment: @L_S are you sure that with floppyforms i can return value to views from template. If yes could you help me I can make it work.